# Edit default text for a file extension in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++, templates

Is it possible to make Notepad++ use a default set of text when I change the language to say php or perl? Basically I am lazy and say for perl I don't have to have to write out

`#/usr/bin/perl`

everytime or the  tags in php.

Edit:
I am avoiding the use of macros.

Answer (score -1):

Notepad++ does not know what language you are intending to use when you open a new document.  You could specify a template that Notepad++ opens up from a shortcut something like

```
notepad++ -lperl -ro /path/to/template
```

You might also consider the [snippets](http://www.fesevur.com/nppsnippets) plugin to simplify the typing.

Comment: notepad++ should know what language I am working in if I chose perl, it knows to syntax for perl.